# How to force eclipse to use latest download plugin

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have implemented headless update in eclipse rcp application, but when I restarting the application it is still using old plugin and not deleting old pluing during update. How can force eclipse to use latest download plugin. Please let me know if any further information is needed. 
I can't use `-clearPersistedState` as it will impact my application preferences.

Comment: Possibly `-clean` which resets the plugin cache. Did you change the version number of the plugin? It needs to be incremented in at least one of the major/minor/micro values for Eclipse to see it as different.

Comment: yes I used `-clean` as well. yes I am updating and update is working fine but it is still loading old plugin. I will double check it though